# O que são e como funcionam os arquivos gch?

Tags: gcc

Recentemente me deparei com um arquivo com a extensão `.gch` em um de meus projetos, isso ocorreu por que acabei passando um arquivo `.h` para ser compilado no `gcc`.

```
$ gcc -c arquivo.h
$ ls
arquivo.c
arquivo.h
arquivo.h.gch
```

> **O que é o arquivo com a extensão `.gch` gerado pelo compilador?**
>
> **Como posso utilizar esse formato de arquivo?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arquivos com extensão `.h.gch` são arquivos de cabeçalho pré-compilados pelo **GCC**, eles servem para a importar os cabeçalhos igual um arquivo `.h`.

Ao importar um biblioteca em **C/C++** *(como **my_math.h**)* poderia usar um arquivo pré-compilado **my_math.h.gch**.

Para importar esse cabeçalho junto ao arquivo `.c`, pode-se importar normalmente como se fosse um arquivo de cabeçalho normal `#include my_math.h` *(não precisa passar o `.gch`)*

**Fontes:**

> https://codare.aurelio.net/2007/05/11/cpp-pre-compilacao-de-headers-no-gcc/

Answer (score 1):

Arquivo com extensão`.gch`refere-se ao [cabeçalho pré-compilado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) do [GCC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), e uma forma de gerá-los, é passando um arquivo de cabeçalho, `.h`, como fonte ao compilador. <sup>[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60577/10707951)</sup>

**Utilizá-lo é transparente para o desenvolvedor**, já que o compilador, quando encontra`#include "arquivo.h"`, primeiro verifica se não existe`arquivo.h.gch` no mesmo caminho, e apenas na inexistência deste, interpreta o`arquivo.h`. <sup>[4](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html)</sup>

**NOTA**

O cabeçalho pré-compilado (acrônimo em inglês, *PCH*, para *pre-compiled header*) é uma **importante ferramenta para diminuir o tempo de compilação** de projetos complexos, com muitos arquivos. Mas **devem obedecer algumas regras para que esse ganho possa ser atingido**, ou em alguns casos, terão até mesmo um tempo de compilação superior à não utilizá-lo. <sup>[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903228/why-use-precompiled-headers-c-c)</sup> <sup>[6](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Precompiled_Headers_Overview)</sup>

Em linhas gerais, **projetos pequenos não requerem tal recurso**, portanto, se em um projeto criado por você aparece um cabeçalho pré-compilado que você não tem conhecimento, procure configurar a sua compilação, abstendo-se da utilização do recurso. <sup>[7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293569/10707951)</sup>